# Vowpal Wabbit unbalanced classes

Tags: classification, vowpalwabbit

I'm trying to fit the model for binary classification and predict the probability of values belonging to these classes.

My first problem is that I can't interpret the results. I have a training set in which`labels=0` and `labels=1` (not `-1 and +1`).

I run the model:

`vw train.vw -f model.vw --link=logistic`

Next:

`vw test.vw -t -i model.vw -p pred.txt`

Then I have a file `pred.txt` with these values:

`0.5
 0.5111
 0.5002
 0.5093
 0.5`

I don't understand what mean 0.5? All value in `pred.txt` about 0.5. I wrote the script and deducted from results 0.5. I get this lines:

`0
 0.111
 0.002
 0.093
 0`

Is that my desired probability?

And here is my second problem - I have unbalanced target class. I have a 95% negative (0) and 5% positive results (1). How can I prescribe that VW made the imbalance of classes, like `{class 0:0.1, class 1:0.9}`?

Or it should be done when preparing dataset?

Answer (score 3):

For binary classification in VW, the labels need to be converted (from 0 and 1) to -1 and +1, e.g. with `sed -e 's/^0/-1/'`.

In addition to `--link=logistic` you need to use also `--loss_function=logistic` if you want to interpret the predictions as probabilities.

For unbalanced classes, you need to use [importance weighting](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Input-format) and tune the importance weight constant on heldout set (or cross-validation) with some external evaluation metric of your choice (e.g. AUC or F1).

See also:

[Calculating AUC when using Vowpal Wabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264516/calculating-auc-when-using-vowpal-wabbit/24660520#24660520)

[Vowpal Wabbit Logistic Regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26833841/vowpal-wabbit-logistic-regression/26842608#26842608)

[How to perform logistic regression using vowpal wabbit on very imbalanced dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634602/how-to-perform-logistic-regression-using-vowpal-wabbit/24659011#24659011)